# HTML button not hiding with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 buttons on my page:

```
<button name="showLoginDiv" onclick="toggleLoginButton('button1','button2')" id="button1">Login</button><br>
<button name="showCreateDiv" onclick="toggleCreateButton('button1','button2')" id="button2">Create Account</button><br>
```

And these Javascript functions at the top of the page:

```
function toggleLoginButton(id1, id2) {
    document.getElementById(id1).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(id2).style.display = 'none';

    // show login form
    var LoginForm = document.getElementById('loginForm');
    LoginForm.style.display = 'block';
}

function toggleCreateButton(id1, id2) {
    document.getElementById(id1).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(id2).style.display = 'none';

    // show create account form
    var CreateForm = document.getElementById('createForm');
    CreateForm.style.display = 'block';
}
```

When I click either of the buttons, I want them both to disappear, and a form to show. The first button disappears correctly, but the second button doesn't, the form appears afterwards so it is not getting stuck on that line. Both buttons should disappear and a form then appears. Something is wrong with one of the `style.display = 'none'` lines.

edit: before and after clicking button screenshots:
[image: before]

[image: after]

[image: after suggested solution]

Comment: This works just fine: http://jsbin.com/teducipequ/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Not for me, i'll post screenshots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, the problem was (for some reason) the box shadow of the buttons was being left behind. I've changed that on button click as well and it works fine now

Answer (score 3):

Ditto to @Gilad Artzi's comment, your code seems to work (https://jsfiddle.net). I combined both of your functions and hard-coded the button ID's. Does this altered HTML work for you?

```
<!-- Buttons -->

<button name="showLoginDiv" onclick="showForm('loginForm')" id="button1">Login</button>
<br>

<button name="showCreateDiv" onclick="showForm('createForm')" id="button2">Create Account</button>
<br>

<!-- Forms -->

<form id="loginForm">
    <div>
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="mail">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" id="mail" name="user_mail" />
    </div>
    <button name="login">Login</button>
</form>

<form id="createForm">
    <div>
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="mail">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" id="mail" name="user_mail" />
    </div>
    <button name="create">Create Account</button>
</form>

<script>
function showForm(formID) {
    document.getElementById("button1").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("button2").style.display = 'none';

    var form = document.getElementById(formID);
    form.style.display = 'block';
}
</script>
```

Comment: Your refactor was exactly how I was going to suggest doing it.

Comment: It might work if I put both buttons in a div and hide the div instead of individually hiding the buttons

Comment: Good idea, that should be much more reliable. What happens when you inspect the blue circle element? What styles are computed for it? (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/?hl=en)